# Converting a Java date stored in SQL Server to a Readable Date/Time

Tags: java, sql-server

We are using a third-party Java application that is storing some date/time info in an SQL Server database.  In order for the application to be database agnostic, it stores this info in a VARCHAR(15) column.  I need to be able to access this in a readable format and from what I have read from the site and the Java docs I have come up with the following:

```
declare @javadate varchar(15);
select @javadate = '001439586176038'  -- Sample date from the DB

select dateadd(mi, datediff(mi, sysutcdatetime(), sysdatetime()), dateadd(s, cast(cast(@javadate as bigint)/1000 as integer), '1/1/1970 00:00:00'));
```

In the above example, I am just using a fixed example in @javadate (I would actually turn the last statement in to a function) but I want to know if this is an accurate way to get the value I want and if there is a better way to do this.

**EDIT: I should mention that the date/time is stored in UTC (thus the need for the datediff).

Comment: Why not store the date/time as long instead of varchar? Also, if you are trying to be database agnostic wont things like systedatetime(), dateadd, etc. defeat this goal? Why not just select the date as the text it is stored at and do the conversion in java?

Comment: This is not my application so I have no control of how things are stored.  I am just trying to read the data from the DB directly to allow for some reporting/mass changes.

Comment: Understood, but I would still recommend not using the vendor specific functions in the query and would recommend doing the data processing in Java.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no knowledge of Java so I can't do any of the processing in the language.  I'm just doing this for my installation and it is not going to be redistributed so vendor specific functions is not a problem.